# get previous screen when click on go back button,

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I created push notification expo.
when I receive a notification and click on it, I navigate to the screen that is called productDetail to display for example the product's detail A by the instuction:
navigation.push('detailProduct',{idProduct:notification.data.idProduct}).
the cause that lets me to use navigation.push is to use the function componentDidMount each time when I navigate to detailProduct screen, however navigation.navigate does not allow me.
and when I receive the notification of product B, I navigate to the 
productDetail screen to display the detail of B.
so my problem is: when I click the return button I do not get the product detail A. Knowing I'm using redux to store the data.
How can I solve this problem or what is the best method that allows me to save the detail product A

Answer (score 0):

> for react-navigation

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.props.navigation.goback() }}>
 <Text>Go Back</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

> for react-native-router-flux

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Actions.pop() }}>
 <Text>Go Back</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help.
but, I noticed something in native react:
when I use setsate and this.state my problem is solved, however the reducer does the problem, does not allow me to get previous screen.
Please can you explain to me why?